# Как присвоить строке в StringList порядковый номер?

Tags: delphi, webbrowser

Есть таймер в котором каждые 3 секунды выполняется цикл поиска ключевого слова `!help` из `TStringList` который содержит исходный код страницы с чатом:

```
  fnd:='!help';
  Ishodnik.Clear;
  Ishodnik.Add(GetHtml(WB_Doc));
  for i:=0 to Ishodnik.Count - 1 do
    if pos(fnd, Ishodnik.Strings[i]) > 0 then 
    begin
      Label1.Caption:='Ключевое слово найдено';
      SpeedButton2.Click;
    end 
    else 
      Label1.Caption:='Ключевое слово отсутствует';
```

Как присвоить порядковый номер строке в которой было найдено ключевое слово и игнорировать его при повторном сканировании?
Пробовал присвоить `Object` найденной строке со значением `1`, но при проверке в `label` получал значение `-1`.

**UPD:** Теперь строка `TStringList` содержащая исходный `html` код страницы разбита на строки после символа "`>`" (TStringList содержит 14300 строк):

```
  fnd:='!help';
  Ishodnik.Clear;
  Ishodnik.Delimiter:='>';
  Ishodnik.DelimitedText:=GetHtml(WB_Doc);
  for i:=0 to Ishodnik.Count - 1 do
  if pos(fnd, Ishodnik.Strings[i]) > 0 then
  begin
    Label1.Caption:='Ключевое слово найдено';
    SpeedButton2.Click;
  end
  else
    Label1.Caption:='Ключевое слово отсутствует';
```

Comment: У Вас в `Ishodnik` всего одна строка - какой порядковый номер? "Пробовал присвоить Object..." - покажите код.

Comment: Хотите сказать список строк получаемый из исходного кода `html` страницы заносится в StringList в виде одной строки?

Comment: `ShowMessage(IntToStr(Ishodnik.Count));`

Comment: Действительно.. Одна.. А писали список строк..Тогда всё становится ещё сложнее, по крайней мере для меня. Присваивал Object так: Ishodnik.AddObject(Ishodnik.Strings[i], TObject(1));

Comment: Вам должны подойти TStringList.Delimiter и TStringList.DelimitedText. Только надо 1. разобраться разделяются ли html строки в тексте страницы и чем, и 2. не использовать TStringList.Objects для запоминания индексов, так как все содержимое списка `Ishodnik` полностью обновляется.

Comment: Или `TStringList` вообще не нужен, а запоминать надо последнюю позицию строки '!help' и в следующий раз начинать искать оттуда.

Comment: А как это без `TStringList` запоминать позицию строки с `!help`?

Comment: Заведите член класс `integer` и присваивайте ему значение, которое возвращает `Pos`. Или, если Вы настаиваете на использовании `TStringList`a, запоминайте в эту пременную индекс строки с '!help', и в следующий раз начинайте цикл со следующего индекса.

Comment: Да, еще. Мне кажется, Вам надо прерывать цикл, если слово найдено. Потому что проверкой следующей строки Вы затрете текст в `Label1`.

Comment: Извините если задаю глупый вопрос, но как начинать поиск в цикле со следующего индекса если `i:=0` в `for i:=0 to Ishodnik.Count - 1 do`?

Comment: Посмотрите ниже - в ответе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type
TForm1 = class(TForm)
...
private
  fPreviousIndex: integer;
  procedure Search;
...
end;

implementation

...

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fPreviousIndex := -1;
end;

procedure TForm1.Search;
var
  i: integer;
  foundNew: boolean;
begin
  ...
  foundNew := false;
  for i := fPreviousIndex + 1 to Ishodnik.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if Pos(fnd, Ishodnik.Strings[i]) > 0 then
    begin
      foundNew := true;
      fPreviousIndex := i;
      break;
    end;
  end;
  if foundNew then
  begin
    Label1.Caption := 'Ключевое слово найдено';
    SpeedButton2.Click;
  end
  else
    Label1.Caption := 'Ключевое слово отсутствует';
end;
```

Comment: Пока не могу понять по какой причине, но сообщение в `label` "Ключевое слово отсутствует" при том что фактически оно присутствует.

Comment: Убедитесь, что Вы правильно/полно перенесли мой код к себе.

Comment: Причину установил - моя невнимательность. Забыл добавить `Ishodnik.Clear;Ishodnik.Delimiter:='>'; Ishodnik.DelimitedText:=GetHtml(WB_Doc);`. Но почему то реакция идет дважды. Т.е. ответное сообщение в чат поступает два раза (SpeedButton2.Click).

Comment: У нас с Вами происходит что-то вроде диалога, но Вы отвечаете каким-то своим мыслям. Что такое "реакция" и "ответное сообщение"?

Comment: Эмм, прошу прощения. `SpeedButton2.Click` отправляет сообщение в чат и теперь это происходит дважды. Т.е. находит `!help` и отвечает в чат `Testing help message` дважды.

Comment: Вы используете мой код цикла или Ваш?

Comment: Использую Ваш код. Он совершает действие `SpeedButton2.Click` дважды или иными словами обрабатывает найденное ключевое слово `!help` два раза.

Comment: Значит метод `Search` вызывается два раза. Потому что внутри `Search` только один вызов `SpeedButton2.Click;`.

Comment: Я перенес код Вашей процедуры в сам таймер в надежде исправить это.

Comment: Дело в самом коде, `SpeedButton2.Click` написано один раз. Он почему то находит `!help` дважды.

Comment: Хм, изменил в данной строке `for i := fPreviousIndex + 1 to Ishodnik.Count - 1 do` +1 на +10 и теперь все работает идеально! Спасибо Вам огромное за помощь! Чтобы я без Вас делал? Около недели пытался сам сделать, в итоге как всегда мне помогли на этом замечательном сайте. Ещё раз огромное Вам спасибо!

Comment: На здоровье, конечно. Успехов в программировании. Однако, неплохо было бы разобраться, что там происходит с этим повторным вызовом. Может, слово, которое мы ищем, встречается в html больше одного раза? Сохраните Ishodnik в файл (TStringList.SaveToFile) и изучите содержимое. Если я прав, надо изменить логику поиска.

Comment: Скорее всего - просто убирание строки `break;` поправит дело.